# esp8266 IR led and transmitter

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I need to detect if the IR led is on. I have an esp8266 and an IR receiver. How do I code this?
I don't need to detect different signals, like a TV remote's individual keys, just if the LED is on or off. I tried just reading the digital input, but got "1.00" every time.

```
float val;
int pin = 1;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
val = digitalRead(pin);

Serial.print(val);
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: why do you have to use ESP8266 module for this you can get a direct code for arduino just IR receiver and arduino pin 3 is enough for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please assign the pin mode for your input pin 1.

Try below code:

```cpp
int val;
int pin=1;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    val=digitalRead(pin);
    Serial.println(val);
    delay(1000);
}
```